# Loading MAT file into Python with different data types

Tags: python, scipy, mat

I have some MAT files whose entries are all float type except for the last column, which are single characters (i.e. "s", "b", etc...)

How do I load in this kind of mixed array into Python? The code I have so far is the following:

```
import scipy.io

train_mat = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/user/data/training.mat')
test_mat = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/user/data/testing.mat')

print train_mat
```

The output is resembles the following:

```
{'training': array([[  1.00000000e+05,   1.38470000e+02,   5.16550000e+01, ...,
          1.13497000e+02,   2.65331130e-03,              nan],
       [  1.00001000e+05,   1.60937000e+02,   6.87680000e+01, ...,
          4.62260000e+01,   2.23358449e+00,              nan],
       [  1.00002000e+05,  -9.99000000e+02,   1.62172000e+02, ...,
          4.42510000e+01,   2.34738894e+00,              nan],
       ...,
```

I'd like the 'nan' at the end of each row to be the proper char ("s", "b", etc...) when working with it in python

Comment: What the version level of these MATLAB files?  How does it compare with the levels described in the `io.loadmat` docs?  What `loadmat` parameters have you tried?

Comment: In `numpy` there are 2 ways of mixing numbers and strings - as record arrays, such as what `getfromtxt` loads from `csv` files, and as arrays of `dtype=object`.  I don't think `loadmat` handles either.  What, exactly, is the Matlab type?  Regular matrix or cell?  or structure?

Comment: @hpaulj it is a regular matrix type